# Can I create my own scaffolding resource i.e. add presentation model purposes 'controller'

Tags: grails, scaffolding

Due to using Grails app also as open-dolphin server, I'd like to be able to scaffold presentation model from domain classes. Since I need to put them into shared package to include them also to client, putting them in standard controller scaffold source is not suitable for me.

So, the question is: Is it possible to add extra scaffolding source beside controller, edit, create, show, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can, just do "grails install-templates" and add new actions to the scaffolded controller: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/scaffolding.html

Comment: I'll have a look if there is way to configure more sources to scaffold, to make it bit 'cleaner' and configurable,  but this is definitely good way to do it, and configuration can be asked via some condition also, so thank you for solving answere.